# Flash content not loading

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome, flash, flash-player

I am trying to get this site to load the flash content:

http://kids.daum.net/study/do/studyflash/view?id=7

I have done everything in the following two links still with no luck:

http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/installation-problems-flash-player-windows.html

http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/flash-player-games-video-or.html

Does anyone have any ideas of the cause of this issue and a solution?

[image]

[image]